# Amazon ELB + jmeter

Tags: jmeter, amazon-elb

I am testing my application using jmeter tool. I am having 2 EC2 m1.small instances behind an ELB (not autoscaling group), 2 caching nodes huge RDS db (Multi-AZ). My Apache (peforked) is configured with default values like 256 maxclients. Both can handle 256-256 request. Now when jmeter throws 500 request I see **connection time out** error in one of sampler of the jmeter. Can anyone figure out what the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500 requests, consecutive? 500 threads with one request?

Answer (score 0):

What does JMeter throw back?
There are couple of things that could happen.

1. Connection reset: If this error is thrown out from your JMeter then it means that the server has maxed out and cannot support any more concurrent requests. i.e. the 256 threads allotted are all in use serving other requests and this basically means you have hit your limit on the server.
2. "Address already in use" exception: These kinds of errors are what you must not get when you do load tests. This basically means that there are no available ports on your system make more requests and all ports are busy. This could happen for a variety of reasons but you could try tweaking system settings like ulimit for linux or if your using a windows box you may want to look at the tcpTimedWaitDelay and corresponding settings to see the average turn around time for the ports to be handed over back into the active pool to be reused for the next connection. This condition is called tcp port exhaustion ([http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?TopicId=6956&Topic=How-to-tune-the-TCP%2FIP-stack-for-high-volume-of-web-requests](http://www.outsystems.com/NetworkForums/ViewTopic.aspx?TopicId=6956&Topic=How-to-tune-the-TCP/IP-stack-for-high-volume-of-web-requests))

   TO get around this you could also try distributed load testing and/or use timers to ensure that you always have the ports to make new connections.

Comment: What does the server logs say? It seems like a load issue. You can try increasing the max_threads in tomcat's server.xml to see if your getting better results.